# Java Lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Lambda expressions are being added in Java 8. I want to understand why this is important. What does it mean to a Java programmer who is yet to be exposed to functional programming idioms? Does it mean I can write code that performs better or scales massively or does it only make the code less verbose. Or all of it.

Comment: I took a class on the organization of programming languages, how my professor told me is that you can make your code lazy. You also, I still don't understand this one, can "get to the top of the mountain"? But really, it confused the hell outta me, can't wait to see the answers.

Comment: Hmm one use I can see is runtime choosing and creation of functions. Suppose you do something to an object and depending on what you did you need to pass it to one of 100 methods or one method with 100 ifs, with lambdas you can write the one method on the fly with no ifs.

Comment: `E=hc/λ` !!! Cmon man!!

Comment: You can read Maurice Naftaling answer in [Why are lambda expressions being added to Java](http://www.lambdafaq.org/why-are-lambda-expressions-being-added-to-java/). Or you can read Mark Reinhold answer in his article [Closures for Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/closures). Mark also wrote, in his blog, a [Closures Q&A](http://mreinhold.org/blog/closures-qa) which seems to address some of your questions. And there is even an interesting article in JavaWorld about [Understanding the Closures Debate](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-closures.html).

Comment: This may help you. http://javaattop.blogspot.in/2013/09/lambda-expressions-in-java.html

Comment: If you are new to java 8, I recommend https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/whats-new-in-java-8-lambda-expressions.html

Comment: ```interface Lambda {
    Object run(Object... params);
}``` then ```Lambda adder = (params -> (Integer) params[0] + 1);
        P.println(adder.run(2));```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Oracle already has [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) up on the topic.  It lists several great uses cases.

Before I found the link, I was going to say that lambda expressions let you pass "functions" to code.  So you can write code more easily that we used to need a whole mess of interfaces/abstract classes for.  For example, suppose you have code that has some complex loop/conditional logic or workflow.  At one step you want to do something different.  With lambda expressions, you can just pass in that "something different."  Read the tutorial though.  It's very clear.

Comment: I got bit confused because your use of phrase - "*Before I found the link, I was going to say that *". So, after you found the Oracle link, your opinion/thought got changed? I mean you were thinking wrong or "less" and after reading that link you realized there is more to it. The reason I am asking is to me what were mentioning earlier was right and gist of that link, so I want to know if I didn't realize full potential of lambda expressions.

Comment: I meant that was my language. The tutorial phrases it better