# The Logic behind These Two Functions - Java

Tags: java, lambda, return, isomorphism

## Introduction

Let's talk about isomorphism here. I have a class that implementing isomoprhism and it is called **ISO** Class. I have this class from the solution of kata in codewars. Reference of isomorphism can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism). This class have many functions to represent the characteristics of isomoprhism. At first, I can understand the logic behind some functions of the class. But, at some point, I got stuck at these two functions. This give me two problems and those problems can be seen in sections below.

## Problem 1

```
static <A, B> ISO<A, B> isoUnOptional(final ISO<Optional<A>, Optional<B>> iso) {
    return iso(
      a -> iso.fw(Optional.of(a))
            .orElseGet(() -> iso.fw(Optional.empty()).get()),
      b -> iso.bw(Optional.of(b))
            .orElseGet(() -> iso.bw(Optional.empty()).get()));
  }
```

## Problem 2

```
static ISO<Either<Stream<Unit>, Unit>, Either<Stream<Unit>, Void>> isoEU() {
    return iso(
      l -> l.pm(
        ll -> Either.left(Stream.concat(Stream.of(Unit.INSTANCE), ll)),
        r -> Either.left(Stream.empty())),
      r -> r.pm(
        l -> { 
          List<Unit> lu = l.collect(Collectors.toList());
          return lu.isEmpty() ? 
              Either.right(Unit.INSTANCE) :
              Either.left(Stream.generate(() -> 
                  Unit.INSTANCE).limit(lu.size() - 1)); 
        },
        Void::absurd));
}
```

Each function give me a problem. The problem is I don't understand the inner working of the return statement. I know about the [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859992/java-lambda-expressions), but I don't know about the logic of it. Could someone explain to me about the logic of these two problems?

### Note

1. The term of logic in here is same as the term of inner working.
2. The full structure of the code can be seen below.

### Complete Code

The full code: [Full Code of ISO Class](https://pastebin.com/tTdnBDD7)

Comment: Please read this Help Center article: "[How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: ok, let me edit it first.

Comment: "*could you explain to me why the return statement become like that? I really don't get the transformation of the mapping function become like that in the two function I mention.*" Becomes like what? What mapping function? Refer to lines of code and clarify the question.

Comment: Ok, I already edit the question to increase the clarity of the question.

Comment: You didn't clarify anything. "*why the return statement become like that*" Like what? What do you expect it to be and why? What is it instead? What is the method supposed to do? "*I really don't get the construction of lambda function become like that*" Sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Ok i already edit my question, I hope now my question is clear and can be understood easily. Please give me some advice again if my question is still unclear.

Comment: In order to understand the logic - what the methods try to do - ones needs to read through all the `ISO` code and decipher what it's trying to do (and it doesn't seem to do whatever it is too well), then decipher the role of these 2 specific functions in the grand scheme. This is more work than I'd care to put into it and makes the question borderline off topic. I'll pass whenever I see 200 lines of not well-written code.

Comment: Actually, that's not my code, but I'm trying to decipher the code too and seems It's gonna take a long time. Just the two problems above actually make me confused.